# fetching multiple rows from database in django?

Tags: python, database, django, django-views

I have to fetch multiple rows from database based on some condition. There may be one row in database for matching query or multiple rows. I can use get() for one row but it does not fetch multiple rows.

Here is my code:

`value=table.objects.get(col_name=1)` then i can access its data as `value.col` but as i said it gives me error if this query returns more then one row.

I have also tried filter() , `value=table.objects.filter(col_name=1)` but then i can't access its data as `value.col`.

So please suggest me some way how i can fetch multiple rows from database and access columns one by one of those rows.

Thanks !!

Comment: i think i have to use for loop for accessing data if i am using filter , Is i am right ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you must iterate over items from queryset:

```
for item in value:
    item.col
```

Answer (score 3):

```
values = table.objects.filter(col_name=1)
for value in values.all():
    # Do something with value.col
```

Comment: Can you tell me one thing.....I have updated some fields from update function and it successfully updated the database and i can see the updated fields in back end but from admin dashboard it shows me the previous value not updated value , any idea why??

Comment: It is possible your django admin is caching - checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/ and try turning off your cache in your settings.py to see if it updates correctly.

Comment: it doesn't work ..... I have update the database through handlers...is this the reason or not ??

Comment: It's hard for me to diagnose the issue without more information. It may be best to ask a new question on StackOverflow for this new issue with a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
value=table.objects.filter(col_name=1)
```

will return a "django.db.models.query.QuerySet" type which can iterated using 'for' loop